# CRYPTO_num_locks error occurs due to two versions of libcurl on Centos 7

Tags: centos, libcurl, yum

I've trying to build some c++ libraries on a virtual Centos 7 distribution.
For a reason that I haven't found out this os can't see the /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/lib64 where these libraries are installed as other linux distributions do. So I had to add these folders on /etc/ld.so.conf. Then the c++ linker was able to see these libraries. 
However when afterwards I gave

```
 sudo yum update
```

I got the following message:

**/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pycurl.so: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_num_locks**

After searching I found that it was cause due to the existence of two version of libcurl. I gave

```
ldconfig -v | grep libcurl
```

And I got the following :

```
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

Meaning that I installed a new version of libcurl and now two versions coexist.
When I removed the folder paths from the /etc/ld.so.conf then yum worked fine but c++ linker could not find the c++ libaries that my app needs. I also tried to update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH but I had the same problems.
Is there a way to fix this issue without having reinstall the libraries on new location ? Is it safe to remove the older version?

The `ls -lsa /usr/lib64/*curl*` gave

```
 0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Aug 10 10:19 /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0  

 428 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 435120 Nov 14 2016 /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

I tried giving

```
sudo unlink /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0 /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
```

I even gave them as root but every time I give `ldconfig` I get

```
   libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

while before ldconfig gives

```
  libcurl.so.4 -> /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, but I didn't have two versions of curl or pycurl installed on my system.  One of my end user software installs, changed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it didn't include /usr/lib or /usr/lib64.  I tried adding them at the end of the path and I still received the same error. I added them to the front, and no more error.  I have to inquire with my end user if there's a legitimate  reason they excluded the default libraries from the enviroment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The default path for standard libraries, as far as I know, on CentOS is /usr/lib and /usr/lib64. If you compiling from source, without explicitly specify the library path when you use `./configure`, those libraries will be installed by default in /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/lib64 (usually lib64 is found on 64 bit OS). So if the libraries are installed there, you should add those path in **/etc/ld.so.conf** and run a `ldconfig` afterwards;

According to your example:

```
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

libcurl.so.4 is linked to 2 different library versions and I think that's the cause of your issue.

You could remove the second link, `libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0`, leaving **libcurl.so.4** only linked to **libcurl.so.4.4.0**, run ldconfig and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Every time I remove the libcurl.so.4 (with sudo rm) which resides in /usr/lib64 the running of ldconfig  recreates it.Is there a specific way to remove this kind of link?

Comment: Try with `unlink /path/to/libcurl.so.4` and then create a new link with the desired library

Comment: do a `ls -lsa /usr/lib64/*curl*` and check all the links there and make sure that you're linking the right thing

Comment: Can you properly edit the comment and format the text please? It's kinda hard to follow

Comment: Check /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/lib64 and see if there are any other symlinks pointing to that 4.3.0 version. There should be another link to point to that somewhere

Comment: Unfortunatelly there in no other instance of 4.3.0 elsewhere I searched with find and locate and it only existed within /usr/lib64. I assume this something related only with Centos. Any way thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `ldconfig -p` to print the cache and check if there are any entries there. But it's strange since ldconfig does rebuild the cache so it should take into consideration your changes

Comment: ldconfig -p gives

libcurl.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
libcurl.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libcurl.so.4
libcurl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so

and even libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.4.0 when giving ls -l in /usr/local/lib