# libcurl.so There was a problem importing one of the Python modules required to run yum. yum error

Tags: python, centos, libcurl, yum, pycurl

I use CentOS 7 with the default 2.7 python. I got this error while running `yum install`

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pycurl.so: undefined symbol: CRYPTO_num_locks

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

When i ran `ldconfig -v | grep libcurl`

```
libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
```

I figured that i have two symlinks to two different versions of libcurl.so

I removed the link from `/usr/lib64` and `/lib64/`

and then i update the cache of ldconfig by running `sudo ldconfig`

but when i check the folder again `/lib64/` the symlink gets back again, and `ldconfig -p` outputs the same results above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CRYPTO\_num\_locks error occurs due to two versions of libcurl on Centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591298/crypto-num-locks-error-occurs-due-to-two-versions-of-libcurl-on-centos-7)